# Differential geometry and curved space

Tags: differential-geometry

> To calculate the intrinsic curvature, we need to know only the metric gμν; we don’t need
> to know the embedding functions.

I am studying curved space and differential geometry, the author said the quotation: The Theorema Egregium of Gauss. As is the first time i am seeing it, i still don't get what does the quotation really means. Could you say more about it? Particularly the meaning of embedding functions would help a lot, since the author do not said what them mean.

It is necessary to understand general relativity... And, to be honest, i like the subject too, because it is hard. I am not stuckling in the meaning of metric, and another things it can suggest. But, thinking better, i realized that i was assuming this theorem probably as true without even knowing the necessity of it. That is, i was always assuming that given the metric is enough to characterize our geometry. The problem is this embedding functions, intuitively, what i am interpretation is that if we use two different functions (surface) to measure the intrinsic curvature, it will give the same ans

Answer (score 1):

Hitsorically, the Theorema Egregium is a result on the geometry of surfaces in the three dimensionnal space.
If $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a surface, then one can define a metric on $S$ by restricting the scalar product on the tangent spaces, that is
$$g_p(u,v) = \langle u , v \rangle,~ u,v\in T_pS$$
This allow us to talk about $S$ as a metric space in itself. The geometric properties of $S$ are here inherited of the geometry of the ambiant space, $\mathbb{R}^3$. One can define the curvature of $S$ in terms of its second fundamental form, which is an extrinsic object: it closely depends on the embedding $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$.

But what does "depend on the embedding" means? As said earlier, one has defined $(S,g)$ as an intrinsic metric space thanks to the induced metric. If $(S',g')$ is a riemannian intrinsic surface that is isometric to $(S,g)$, that is if there exists a diffeomorphism $f : S \to S'$ with $f^*g' = g$, then one can hope the two object $(S,g)$ and $(S',g')$ have the same geometric properties. For instance, the same curvature? But curvature is defined in terms of the embedding $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$! So maybe, if $S'\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is also a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, they do not have the same curvature because they are not the same surface as embedded in the three dimensional space.

The Theorema Egregium just says that, even if the definition of the curvature here looks like it depends on the embedding (and in the computations, it really looks like!), in reality it does not. Gauss made some horrible calculations to get a formula that does not involve the extrinsic property of the embedding but just the intrinsic property of $(S,g)$. That is, the curvature is a geometric notion that does make sense for a surface in itself, not just for a surface as a subset of the three dimensional space.

It has a natural generalisation for embedded submanifold in riemannian geometry.

With a modern point of view, the Theorema Egregium may look weird because we usually define the curvature in terms of tensor algebra and the Riemann tensor. But in fact, the reason we arrived to the definition of these intrinsics notions (Riemann tensor, sectionnal curvature, *etc*.) is because the Theorema Egregium has been proven, and one could have hoped for an intrinsic notion to defined it!